# Is it possible to have different conditions one based on event and one based on state in Flutter Bloc V8

Tags: flutter, bloc

I Have a listview of posts and I'm adding more posts to the stream using scroll controller. So for this, I wanted to use the Bloc package and I followed the [infinity list tutorial](https://bloclibrary.dev/#/flutterinfinitelisttutorial) which it's great and works well, But then I came to a situation where I'm having another event besides scrolling that I want to show different types of posts that's already categorized on the server-side. After many trials, I came to a solution (I will add the code below) that works great. But I'm a little bit concerned since I'm new to the bloc package, I'm having conditions based on different types. Like if you check the code my first condition is based on the state while the second condition is based on the event. I was wondering if that is the right way? if not can you tell what is the right way please. thanks

```
const throttleDuration = Duration(milliseconds: 100);

EventTransformer<E> throttleDroppable<E>(Duration duration) {
  return (events, mapper) {
    return droppable<E>().call(events.throttle(duration), mapper);
  };
}

class PostBloc extends Bloc<PostEvent, PostState> {
  final NewsRepository _newsRepository = NewsRepository();

  PostBloc() : super(const PostState()) {
    on<PostFetched>(
      _onPostFetched,
      transformer: throttleDroppable(throttleDuration),
    );
  }

  Future<void> _onPostFetched(
    PostFetched event,
    Emitter<PostState> emit,
  ) async {
    if (state.hasReachedMax) return;
    try {
      if (state.status == PostStatus.initial) { //this condition
        final posts = await _newsRepository.fetchAllNews(
            event.language, event.link, event.pageNumber);
        return emit(state.copyWith(
          status: PostStatus.success,
          posts: posts.data,
          hasReachedMax: false,
        ));
      } else if (event.categoryChanged) { //and this condition
        final posts = await _newsRepository.fetchAllNews(
            event.language, event.link, event.pageNumber);
        return emit(state.copyWith(
          status: PostStatus.success,
          posts: posts.data,
          hasReachedMax: false,
        ));
      }
      final posts = await _newsRepository.fetchAllNews(
          event.language, event.link, event.pageNumber);
      posts.data.isEmpty
          ? emit(state.copyWith(hasReachedMax: true))
          : emit(
              state.copyWith(
                status: PostStatus.success,
                posts: List.of(state.posts)..addAll(posts.data),
                hasReachedMax: false,
              ),
            );
    } catch (_) {
      emit(state.copyWith(status: PostStatus.failure));
    }
  }
}
```

HINT: I tried to have different events like below but could not make it work.

```
PostBloc() : super(const PostState()) {
    on<PostFetched>(
      _onPostFetched,
      transformer: throttleDroppable(throttleDuration),
    );
    on<CategoryChanged>(
      _onCategory,
      transformer: throttleDroppable(throttleDuration),
    );
  }
```